# APPLICATION FAILED TO START ::: "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured."

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, url

I am fairly new to Spring Boot and working on a project ,but getting an error of URL attribute not specified in my console.

Application.properties files

```
spring.datasourse.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_directory?useSSL=false&serverTimeZone=UTC
spring.datasourse.username=springstudent    
spring.datasourse.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

My pom.xml file (~generated using spring.io)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>cruddemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cruddemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<!--  -->       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I know my error seems to be in application properties file but i have checked the files and is not able to seems to find any error.

my Appilcation

```
package com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CruddemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CruddemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

my EmployeeDAOImpl

```
package com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Autowired
    public EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        Query<Employee> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Employee", Employee.class);
        
        List<Employee> employees = theQuery.getResultList();
        
        return employees;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee findById(int theId) {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        Employee theEmployee = currentSession.get(Employee.class, theId);
        
        return theEmployee;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Employee theEmployee) {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theEmployee);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int theId) {
        
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("delete from Employee where id=:employeeId");
        
        theQuery.setParameter("employeeId", theId);

        theQuery.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

my EMployeeDAO

```
package com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeDAO {

    public List<Employee> findAll();
    public Employee findById(int theId);
    public void save(Employee theEmployee);
    public void delete(int theId);
}
```

my error screen

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)

2020-08-24 14:03:56.750  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.s.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication       : Starting CruddemoApplication on DESKTOP-AR3MS4U with PID 11608 (D:\Eclipse && STS\eclipse\cruddemo\target\classes started by Abhijay in D:\Eclipse && STS\eclipse\cruddemo)
2020-08-24 14:03:56.763  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.s.cruddemo.CruddemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-24 14:03:56.990  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-08-24 14:03:56.991  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-08-24 14:04:00.471  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-24 14:04:00.493  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-24 14:04:00.494  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-08-24 14:04:00.957  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-24 14:04:00.957  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3965 ms
2020-08-24 14:04:01.323  WARN 11608 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOHibernateImpl' defined in file [D:\Eclipse && STS\eclipse\cruddemo\target\classes\com\luv2code\springboot\cruddemo\dao\EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2020-08-24 14:04:01.331  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-24 14:04:01.380  INFO 11608 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-24 14:04:02.111 ERROR 11608 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.luv2code.springboot.cruddemo.dao.EmployeeDAOHibernateImpl required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' in your configuration.
```

Comment: I am using mySQL workbench as my database and it is already up and running.

Comment: Your post lacks main things: the full error message and when do you have that error (I guess at startup).

Comment: Hi @akuma, i have update my post with the error now, and yes you were right it was at startup.

Comment: The error message is not related to your question's title.

Comment: And since you are using Spring Data Jpa, you do not need to implement CRUD operations yourself. Take a look at `CrudRepository` and `JpaRepository` interfaces.

Comment: @Hülya All operations provided by `JpaRespository` interface use the `EntityManager` so it's a non sens for him to use low level `EntityManager` operations for a basic CRUD. Anyway,  @Abhijay Bisht did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hey @Akuma you mean to say that the 'transactional' is more newer than EntityManager?

Comment: Also NO, after disabling the autoconfig error is show of EntityManager package. I read in stackover flow that the newer version of spring boot has problem in EntityManager. So even after changing my boot version it is shoeing the same error of  "" Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Comment: Thanks guys got the Solution in my Application properties i have to use "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" instead of "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"